# How to prune keras ResNet50 pretrained weights ( .h5 file) ? I only have .h5 weights file. (I've successfully loaded keras weights)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am a beginner.

I got the keras resnet50 pretrained weights (.h5 file), generated the model architecture for it using the official tensorflow api. Now when I try to prune the weights, the size of the weights #file remain the same and the total no. of params in the weights file gets doubled as the non-trainable params gets increase to nearly trainable params.

After loading the keras weights successfully, i tried to prune as below:-

```py
    epochs = 12

    batch_size = 8

    num_train_samples = 5000

    end_step = np.ceil(1.0 * num_train_samples/batch_size).astype(np.int32) * epochs
    print('End step: ' + str(end_step))


    prune_low_magnitude = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude

    pruning_params = {
          'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.10,
                                                                   final_sparsity=0.90,
                                                                   begin_step=0,
                                                                   end_step=end_step,
                                                                   frequency = 10)
    }

    model_for_pruning = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude(model, **pruning_params)

    # `prune_low_magnitude` requires a recompile.

    model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model_for_pruning.summary()

    _, pruned_keras_file = tempfile.mkstemp('.h5')

    tf.keras.models.save_model(model_for_pruning, pruned_keras_file, include_optimizer=False)

    print('Saved pruned Keras model to:', pruned_keras_file)

    def get_gzipped_model_size(file):

      # Returns size of gzipped model, in bytes.

      import os

      import zipfile

      _, zipped_file = tempfile.mkstemp('.zip')

      with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as f:

        f.write(file)


      return os.path.getsize(zipped_file)


    print("Size of gzipped baseline Keras model: %.2f bytes" % (get_gzipped_model_size(keras_file)))

    print("Size of gzipped pruned Keras model: %.2f bytes" % (get_gzipped_model_size(pruned_keras_file)))
```

Now the size of the keras_file is few kilobytes smaller than pruned_keras_file.
what to do?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?